# "Método \"POST\" no permitido." Django, Bulk_Create in django-restframework

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Hice una vista en mi proyecto de Django que me permita subir un tipo de reportes en lote.

```
class HMReportBulkCreateView(APIView):
    """Endpoint para crear reportes en lote"""

    authentication_classes = [FirebaseAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    allowed_methods = ["POST"]  # Permitir solo el método POST

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if "POST" not in self.allowed_methods:
            return Response(
                {"detail": 'Método "POST" no permitido. Validado'}, status=405
            )
        serializer = HMDataSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            hm_reports = serializer.save()

            calculate_risk_score_async.apply_async()

            return Response({"hm_reports": hm_reports}, status=201)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Puedo incluir el serializer y el modelo, pero realmente no creo que eso sea el problema.

Mi archivo urls.py luce así:

```
"""
URL Mapping for the Heatmap API
"""
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from heatmap.views import heatmap_views, testimony_views
from heatmap.views.heatmap_views import (
    get_reports,
    get_testimonies,
    HMReportBulkCreateView,
)

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("testimonies", testimony_views.TestimonyViewSet)
router.register("data", heatmap_views.HeatmapViewSet)
router.register("dept", heatmap_views.HeatmapDeptViewSet)
router.register("munc", heatmap_views.HeatmapMuncViewSet)

app_name = "heatmap"

urlpatterns = [
    path("get_munc_reports/<mun_id>/", get_reports, name="get_munc_reports"),
    path(
        "get_munc_testimonies/<mun_id>/", get_testimonies, name="get_munc_testimonies"
    ),
    path(
        "data/bulk-create/",
        HMReportBulkCreateView.as_view(),
        name="report-bulk-create",
    ),
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

Adicionalmente a la vista para crear archivos en bache estoy incluyendo otros viewsets que tengo con un DefaultRouter(). Todas esas vistas están funcionando bien.

Estoy enviando un payload en postman que luce algo así

```
[{"type_of_aggression": "Robo o eliminaci\u00f3n del material period\u00edstico", "department": 5, "municipality": 80.0}, {"type_of_aggression": "Amenaza", "department": 76, "municipality": 1048.0}, {"type_of_aggression": "Amenaza", "department": 97, "municipality": 1114.0}, {"type_of_aggression": "Amenaza", "department": 15, "municipality": 220.0}, {"type_of_aggression": "Hostigamiento", "department": 81, "municipality": 1053.0}, {"type_of_aggression": "Amenaza", "department": 11, "municipality": 149.0},...]
```

Es una lista con los reportes y está en formato json. La url está correcta y el método es POST.

Sin embargo, estoy recibiendo el mensaje:

```
{
    "detail": "Método \"POST\" no permitido."
}
```

No entiendo la razón, revisé mis MiddleWare pero no hay nada extraño (son los default de django + cors), el routing parece correcto y todo lo demás funciona.

¿Alguna idea de cuál puede ser el problema?

Estoy esperando lograr la creación de varios reportes en lote sin que haya dificultades

Comment: ¿Has intentado decorar tu método post con algo como `@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])`?